# Special functions on the unit disk

Tags: gn.general-topology, euclidean-geometry, real-analysis, recreational-mathematics

Let $\mathbb{D} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ be the unit disk.

We say a function $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ is a **winner** if it satisfies the following:
1) it is a homeomorphism
2) if $f(x) = y$, then $f(y) = x$
3) the only fixed point is the origin $(0,0)$

It is easy to give at least one example of a winner function: the "point reflection" centered at the origin (i.e., a 180-degree rotation). Are there other examples?

As pointed out by Bill Johnson (see below), winners are invariant under conjugation by origin-preserving homeomorphisms. This raises the following question: is there another "conjugacy class" of winners?

Comment: Do you mean "reflection"? I would have thought you meant rotation through 180 degrees

Comment: Yes, a 180-degree rotation is the same thing...

Comment: Oh, I see, I was brought up to use the word reflection for a reflection in a hyperplane (or mirror)

Answer (score 5):

Condition (2) says $f^2=I$. Conjugate your reflection with a homeomorphism that fixes zero and does not commute with your reflection.

Comment: That's correct. But are these the only ones?

Comment: @expmat: your original question just asked for an example which was not rotation through 180 degrees

Comment: @Bill: Excuse me for my ignorance but can you give me examples of such homeomorphisms fixing the origin but not commuting with my reflection?

Comment: Map one to minus one and minus one to any point on the unit circle other than one.  Extend to any homeomorphism that fixes the origin.

Comment: Thanks! Is this the only "conjugacy class"?

Comment: @expmat: just follow the hints Bill Johnson gave to you. If $f$ is an involutory homeomorphism of the disk whose only fixed point is $0$, and $\phi$ is any homeomorphism of the disk, then $\phi f \phi^{-1}$ is an involutory homeomorphism of the disk whose only fixed point is $\phi(0)$. So  $\phi f \phi^{-1}$ is still in the class of involutory homeomorphisms of the disk whose only fixed point is $0$ if and only if $\phi(0)=0$. Thus, no other conjugacy class.  